# Create a list of pandas dataframes with names in pattern

Tags: list, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a list of pandas dataframes with names in some pattern, like list = [df_1, df_2, df_3....] (there are about 15 of them)
I know I can define them one by one and append them into a list. Is there any efficient way to do it?

Comment: just want to create empty dataframes

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should work. Naming variables dynamically in python is not great practice, however, so I would recommend against it:

```
dct = {}
for i in range(0,16):
    dct['df_%s' % i] = pd.DataFrame()

for k,v in dct.items():
    locals()[k] = v
```